# Hosting bare repo on very old version of git

Tags: git

I'm planning to host a few bare repos on a server that is running old versions of git (there are two servers, one with 1.7 and one with 1.8. For reasons that don't matter here, the server with 1.7 is preferred, unless there's a big reason to use 1.8).

My working repos will be local using up-to-date git. Will there be any issues? The repos are currently hosted on github and may in the future move to a private gitlab server, will either of those transfers cause issues? Are there any major modern features that won't be supported or won't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

1.7 is not *very* old, I believe it should be marginally usable, but you are going to risk bugs with some features (for example, shallow clones) and missing security checks which catches malicious content before somebody fetches it. Best way to know what could fail is to open [release notes archive](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) and check what is new for each x.y.0 version after yours.